# Router-View tag doesn't display content with beforeEach()

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, vuetify.js

I have a vue-router that works as designed, but the moment I add the `beforeEach()` function to it, nothing appears in the `<router-view>` tags. Even if the `beforeEach()` function is empty, it still hides the content from the page. I there something else I need to do to make the `<router-view>` tag and router work with each other even with the `beforeEach()` function?

Here is the router:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import Home from './views/Home.vue'

Vue.use(Router)

const router = new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'home',
      component: Home,
      meta: {
        authenticatedRoute: false
      }
    },
    {
      path: '/login',
      name: 'login',
      component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "login" */ './views/Login.vue'),
      meta: {
        authenticatedRoute: true
      }
    }
  ]
})

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  // test
})

export default router;
```

And the `<router-view>` tag:

```
<v-content>
  <router-view></router-view>
</v-content>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your `beforeEach` fails to call `next()`, the route will not resolve.

With that in mind, a completely minimal `beforeEach` would be

```js
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  next()
})
```

From the [documentation](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#global-before-guards)...

> **`next: Function`**: this function must be called to **resolve** the hook.
>   ...
>   **Make sure to always call the `next` function, otherwise the hook will never be resolved.**